# Sort tables in order of dependency - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Purpose is to allow a insert script to add data to all tables in schema, such that it doesn't create any conflict in constraint. i take tables from information_schema.tables and take constraints from information_schema.table_constraints but not sure how to compare to sort tables in order of foreign key constraints. Please favour.

The below produces duplicate table names:

```
select a.table_name,b.ordinal_position
from information_schema.tables a left outer join
     information_schema.key_column_usage b
     on a.table_name = b.table_name
```

Comment: Generate the insert script with `pg_dump` - it will take care of constraints automatically.

Comment: my need is to write a query , right now..

Answer (score 12):

You need a recursive query that traverses the whole dependency tree of foreign key relations.

The following query does this for simple dependencies. It does **not** handle circular foreign keys

```
with recursive fk_tree as (
  -- All tables not referencing anything else
  select t.oid as reloid, 
         t.relname as table_name, 
         s.nspname as schema_name,
         null::text as referenced_table_name,
         null::text as referenced_schema_name,
         1 as level
  from pg_class t
    join pg_namespace s on s.oid = t.relnamespace
  where relkind = 'r'
    and not exists (select *
                    from pg_constraint
                    where contype = 'f'
                      and conrelid = t.oid)
    and s.nspname = 'public' -- limit to one schema 

  union all 

  select ref.oid, 
         ref.relname, 
         rs.nspname,
         p.table_name,
         p.schema_name,
         p.level + 1
  from pg_class ref
    join pg_namespace rs on rs.oid = ref.relnamespace
    join pg_constraint c on c.contype = 'f' and c.conrelid = ref.oid
    join fk_tree p on p.reloid = c.confrelid
  where ref.oid != p.reloid  -- do not enter to tables referencing theirselves.
), all_tables as (
  -- this picks the highest level for each table
  select schema_name, table_name,
         level, 
         row_number() over (partition by schema_name, table_name order by level desc) as last_table_row
  from fk_tree
)
select schema_name, table_name, level
from all_tables at
where last_table_row = 1
order by level;
```

For the following table structure:

```
create table customer (id integer primary key);
create table product (id integer primary key);
create table manufacturer (id integer primary key);
create table manufactured_by (product_id integer references product, manufacturer_id integer references manufacturer);
create table distributor (id integer primary key);
create table orders (id integer primary key, customer_id integer references customer);
create table order_line (id integer primary key, order_id integer references orders);
create table invoice (id integer, order_id integer references orders);
create table delivery (oder_line_id integer references order_line, distributor_id integer references distributor);
```

This returns the following result:

```
schema_name  | table_name      | level
-------------+-----------------+------
public       | customer        |     1
public       | distributor     |     1
public       | manufacturer    |     1
public       | product         |     1
public       | manufactured_by |     2
public       | orders          |     2
public       | order_line      |     3
public       | invoice         |     3
public       | delivery        |     4
```

Which means you need to insert into `customer` before you can insert into `orders`. The order of inserts for tables with the same level does not matter.

The intermediate step with the CTE `all_tables` is necessary to list every table only once. Otherwise the table `manufactured_by` would be listed twice:

```
schema_name | table_name      | level
------------+-----------------+------
public      | customer        |     1
public      | product         |     1
public      | manufacturer    |     1
public      | distributor     |     1
public      | manufactured_by |     2
public      | manufactured_by |     2
public      | orders          |     2
public      | delivery        |     2
public      | order_line      |     3
public      | invoice         |     3
public      | delivery        |     4
```

This query might need more tweaking (especially to prevent cycles in the dependency tree), but it should give you a start.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The original answer from @user330315 was "almost there" for me. I was getting

> ERROR:  recursive query "fk_tree" column 4 has collation "default" in non-recursive term but collation "C" overall
> LINE 6:          null::text as referenced_table_name,
> ^
> HINT:  Use the COLLATE clause to set the collation of the non-recursive term.

Probably depends on default collation setting. To fix, just add specified collation to `null` static columns

```sql
with recursive fk_tree as (
  -- All tables not referencing anything else
  select t.oid as reloid, 
         t.relname as table_name, 
         s.nspname as schema_name,
         null::text  COLLATE "en_US" as referenced_table_name, -- <<<-----
         null::text  COLLATE "en_US" as referenced_schema_name, -- <<<-----
         1 as level
. . . . . . . . . .
```